# Handling expected supervisord exit codes

Tags: centos, supervisord

I am using `supervisord` inside a Docker container to manage my running processes and would like to also use it to trigger certain commands - run them once and expect them to exit with `0`.

Here's one example:

```
[program:central-seed-posts]
command = /usr/bin/php /var/www/app/artisan post
autostart = false
autorestart = false
startsecs = 3
startretries = 0
exitcodes = 0
stderr_logfile=/tmp/central/posts-stderr-supervisor.log
stdout_logfile=/tmp/central/posts-stdout-supervisor.log
```

And I'm using [nsenter's](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) `docker-enter` with `supervisorctl start central-seed-posts` to trigger it but I would also like to handle a successful exit instead of supervisor telling me `ERROR (abnormal termination)`

Does it have to do with supervisor events ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem you are encountering seems to be with the following option you use:

```
startsecs = 3
```

If you read manual of supervisord, you can see that startsecs sets for how long the process has to stay alive after a startup for Supervisord to consider the start successful. Your process is probably exiting before 3 secs, which suggests to supervisord that startup was not successful.

Try lowering that to 0, unless you have a real reason to keep it 3 sec.